# Using GZIP with html pages served from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip

Does anyone know of any problems serving gzipped HTML pages using Amazon S3. I have the need to minimize the file size of our HTML files (ie serving up compressed HTML, CSS and javascript files) - but am concerned that either:

1. Amazon S3 does not serve up gzipped files correctly to the browser that requests it. Or,
2. Some browsers have trouble reading gzipped content. I understand older browsers do not support gzipped content (such as IE6 and earlier) - and some (modern?) anti-virus software will strip the content-encoding headers.

Do I need to serve up uncompressed HTML (which I believe Amazon S3 will support easily) - or can I rest assured that most modern browsers will handle my gzipped content okay?

Answer (score 11):

Gzip the file and add the following metadata entry to the S3 object before uploading it:

```
Content-Encoding=gzip
```

Comment: this is generating a ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED in browsers, the best is to make a script that automatize gzip compression then upload to s3.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 does not support gzipped content automatically, but you can manually change the content encoding headers before you upload the content. It will dutifully serve the content back as content type gzip. However, if your file extensions are .gz, then safari will treat it like an attachment, so you have to use .jgz as a file extension.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. The extension has less to do with how the file is treated by browsers versus the Content-Type and Content-Encoding response headers.

Comment: thesmart - I did test this and found that safari will not respect content-encoding= gzip if the file extension is .gz, but I might have screwed the test up

Comment: Michael: ah, didn't realize you were referring to a bug in Safari.  .gz.js works fine as an extension, from my experience.