# Serving gzip content from on Amazon S3 - doesn't work with my application

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, gzip

I've gziped my JavaScript file using gzip and uploaded it to Amazon S3. I've set the following:

```
content-type: application/x-javascript
content-encoding: gzip
```

The file was given `public` permissions.

The problem that when I refer the script to the location (correct one, I've checked) of the gzipped file (with `js.gzip` at the end), the application doesn't run it. When I tried to view the file in Chrome browser, it tried to download the file instead of showing it.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384508/using-gzip-with-html-pages-served-from-amazon-s3/3384520#3384520) of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384508/using-gzip-with-html-pages-served-from-amazon-s3), there's a bug in Safari (probably Webkit) which stops proper gzip acceptance with the "wrong" file extension.

File extension shouldn't matter, but apparently Webkit screws it up. try either `.jgz` or `.gz.js`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove:

```
content-type: application/x-javascript
```

and only use:

```
content-encoding: gzip
```

in your S3 bucket `file.js` file (gziped, replace `.js.gz` for `.js` only).
Now the browser request should work without any problem.