# Serving GZipped files from s3 using the Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.2.3 app on Heroku and I'm using the [asset_sync gem](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) to serve my assets from s3, via [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31).  It works great, except s3 is not serving up the gzipped css/js files (just the uncompressed version).  I've enabled gzip compression, to no avail:

```
config.gzip_compression = true
```

According to [Using GZIP with html pages served from Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384508/using-gzip-with-html-pages-served-from-amazon-s3/3384520#3384520) I need to add meta-data to the s3 object for uploading.  How would I do this in concert with the Asset Pipeline?  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Set up this environment variable on your heroku instance:

```
heroku config:add ASSET_SYNC_GZIP_COMPRESSION=true
```

You can see this option on the [readme for asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync).